# error: invalid source release: 1.17 whiling using openJDK17 to build

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-plugin, java-17

I updated the `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` of my maven project from both `1.8` to `1.17` and I also updated my JDK to `openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17`.

I confirm my maven version is also using jdk17 by running `mvn -v`.

```
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec
Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.6/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.6.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

But I am still seeing this error `invalid source release: 1.17`.
Is there anything I should check?

BTW, I do not see this error if my `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` are both `1.8` while using the JDK17 to compile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versioning for java has changed after version 1.8. The newer versions are without `1.`

So your version must be 17.

```
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>  
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
```